# Preserving macOS window aspect ratio

Tags: macos, resize, window, scenekit

I load a scene in sceneKit and a window is automatically created. That window is resizable. Can I gain some control over the resizing process, so as to force it to preserve a certain aspect ratio as it grows or shrinks? For that matter, can I control the size and shape of the window as it is first created?

I preferably wish to do this programmatically, not using the Storyboard, but I'm open to either.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on in this question.

You can control the aspect ratio of an NSWindow by settings its [aspectRatio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419507-aspectratio).

Typically, though, you don't want to do that.  You usually care about the aspect ratio of some view (a SCNView, perhaps), not the window.  Use [layout constraints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint) to fix the aspect ratio of your views, and the window they're contained in will naturally have a correct aspect ratio, too.

Also: Storyboards aren't the opposite of programmatic.  Interface Builder is.  You can do Storyboards entirely programmatically, too.